# Send echo or register contents to pbcopy / mac clipboard on mac os x

Tags: vim, pbcopy

I have a custom function in vimscript which creates a string and then echo's it to the bottom console.  At the moment I copy and paste that output using cmd-c to copy it to the mac os x clipboard.  I would like to shorten this workflow by just piping the echo to pbcopy, i tried:

```
:echo "hello" <BAR> !pbcopy
```

But of course that doesn't work.  I also tried capturing the output into a register and then outputting it:

```
:@a!pbcopy
```

But it just trys to execute the string stored in @a, which is no a vim command.  I feel like this should be straight forward, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Piping buffer to external command in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867356/piping-buffer-to-external-command-in-vim)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `pbcopy` takes its input from `stdin` you could try using `system()`

```
:call system('pbcopy', 'hello')
:call system('pbcopy', @a)
```

For more information see

```
:h system()
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of Vim do you use? In any reasonably up-to-date version (installed via Mac Ports/Homebrew or, better, MacVim) a simple

```
let @*="text"
```

will put `text` on the clipboard.

See `:h clipboard`.

Comment: I am using the default install of vim, which is 7.3
When I try to set @* I get an error, "Invalid register name: '*'"

Comment: @DubsGordon: The (compile-time) `cilpboard` feature controls whether that register is available (the MacVim author contributed the support for the OS X pasteboard to Vim 7.3). Your default installation of Vim probably does not include the feature (i.e. `-clipboard` in the output of `:version`), but as romainl indicates, many other builds do include it (`+clipboard`).

Comment: @DubsGordon, you'll make your life considerably easier by installing a proper build. I'd recommend MacVim.