# Piping current buffer as a string(!) to an external command

Tags: shell, vim

I have a problem piping the current buffer to an external command. Similar questions asked could not solve the problem.

I want to treat the content of the buffer as a string and simply pass it as an argument like this, where %s is the CONTENT of my file:

```
:!thunderbird.exe -compose body=%s
```

The usual way of using `%w !{cmd}` is not working here, because thunderbird doesn't read from STDIN, correct me if this assumption is wrong. ([Piping buffer to external command in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867356/piping-buffer-to-external-command-in-vim))

How do I send my buffer content as a string to an external command?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the contents of a whole file into an ex command is going to be difficult because you will need to escape the text. As an alternative I would suggest creating a function to copy the contents of the file to the clipboard and then open a new email and simply paste the contents into the body.

```
function! Send()
  :%yank +
  :silent !thunderbird.exe -compose
  :redraw!
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>s :call Send()<cr>
```

Comment: I think :redraw is what you want for ^L

Comment: I did try using `:redraw`, unfortunately it doesn't have the same effect as `^L`.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/redraw-vs-Ctrl-L-difference-td1200223.html 

If you messed up the screen in a way that Vim doesn't know about it,
such as with an external command, you need to use ":redraw!".

Although now that I re-read `:h :redraw` it's there too. doh.