# How to "copy to clipboard" in vim of Bash on Windows?

Tags: bash, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I used to use `"+y` to copy text to system's clipboard, but it doesn't work in vim of Bash on Windows.

Comment: You can't. Use GVim if you want clipboard support on Windows.

Comment: The `"*` register does the trick for vim in git bash. E.g. to copy the current line: `"*yy` (then ctrl-v into e.g. your web browser URL field). Or the other way around: (e.g. after copying e.g. a URL), paste it into your current vim file: `"*p`.

Comment: I don't understand how this question was closed. Of course `vim` is a software tool primarily used by programmers. Was it closed because this question was asked related to Windows?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since neither "*y nor "+y (...) work, an alternative is the following:

Add this to your `.vimrc` and create a file called `~/.vimbuffer`

```
" copy (write) highlighted text to .vimbuffer
vmap <C-c> y:new ~/.vimbuffer<CR>VGp:x<CR> \| :!cat ~/.vimbuffer \| clip.exe <CR><CR>
" paste from buffer
map <C-v> :r ~/.vimbuffer<CR>
```

Higlight any text using visual or visual-block and press `ctrl-c`.
Paste copied text outside your terminal using the usual method or
paste copied text to any vim pane using `ctrl-v` in normal or visual mode.

`Ctrl-c` yanks the selected text, overwrites `~/.vimbuffer` with the selected text, runs a UNIX command to pipe out the data from `~/.vimbuffer` to `clip.exe.`

Any further improvement (e.g.: making command silent) is much appreciated!

**Edit:**
 command can now  copy strings with any length, not just whole lines.
Old command:

`vmap <C-c> :w! ~/.vimbuffer \| !cat ~/.vimbuffer \| clip.exe <CR><CR>`

**Edit2**: @Tropilio below has a much cleaner approach down in the comments using system events. I've been using that for a year now.

Comment: For some reason, it does not work for me.  It inserts two chars `:|`  ( colon and pipe chars) at the very beginning of the selection and it does not copy the contents to windows clipboard. When there is contents in `.vimbuffer`, and I enter `:!cat ~/.vimbuffer \| clip.exe <cr>` into vim, I get the following error: `cat: '|' : no such file or directory` and `cat: clip.exe: No such file or directory`

Comment: This might be because you're using the command from inside vim. If you simply want to copy the content of `~/.vimbuffer` to clipboard, use
`:!cat ~/.vimbuffer | clip.exe <cr>` - you don't have to escape the | char (with a \) from vim, only in `.vimrc`. Let me know if it still not working.

Comment: I can confirm this works on the latest WSL on Windows 10.                    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.286]

Comment: Thanks, this works! But for some reason, whenever I use the `<C-c>` command, there's a glitch where the screen flickers a couple of times...

Comment: @Tropilio Yes, unfortunately that happens for me, too. I think the flicker happens because of the repeated "bang!"s. I was trying to make the script work by using vim's syscall (vim not having to be suspended), but the piping failed.

Comment: I am now using a different approach, maybe it can be useful to you as well. I use an autocommand that gets automatically triggered everytime I yank some text:
`autocmd TextYankPost * call system('echo '.shellescape(join(v:event.regcontents, "\<CR>")).' |  clip.exe')` This doesn't cause any flicker or lag.

Comment: @Tropilio Wow, TextYankPost is a great idea! This works really well with my other hack:
`noremap <silent><RightMouse> :let @9 = trim(system("paste.exe")) \| normal "9p <CR>`
For this you need [paste.cs](https://github.com/davidanderle/dotfiles/blob/master/paste.cs) (or something similar) compiled to paste.exe and placed in your System32 directoly (where clip.exe lives).

Answer (score 31):

To copy to the clipboard from within vim in Bash on Windows 10, hold `Shift` and drag the cursor over text. then press `enter`

A selection should look like this before pressing `enter`:

[image: Selection should look like this before pressing ENTER]

**EDIT**: This only works with text that fits on the screen all at once; it cannot be used to copy blocks of text that span many 'screens'

Comment: This copies the text from the console though and not in vim per se.

Comment: Correct, but I do not know of a way that doesn't. (If you want to use the stock vim that comes bundled with WSL)

Comment: vim help on my (non-Windows) system claims that `"*` is the correct register to use.

Comment: Right, but it requires vim to be installed in a different way, `vim-gnome` instead of just `vim`

Comment: *shrug* I suppose they decided that vim running under WSL didn't need to actually integrate with Windows at all.

Answer (score 14):

So there's a lot of answers, even on cross-network questions like [this one on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1291425/windows-subsystem-linux-make-vim-use-the-clipboard), and [this one on Vi and Vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12376/vim-on-wsl-synchronize-system-clipboard-set-clipboard-unnamed), and unfortunately I'm not satisfied with any of them, so here's a different answer.

### Neovim

If we're using Neovim, it's easy. We can follow their FAQ under [How to use the Windows clipboard from WSL](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/FAQ#how-to-use-the-windows-clipboard-from-wsl). The rest of this section is just context.

By setting `set clipboard=unnamedplus` as if we were on a regular Linux system under X11, we tell Neovim to use the system registers as our default clipboard when yanking and pasting. Based on where Neovim is running, it chooses an appropriate provider to interact with these system registers. For v0.4.3, how that provider is chosen can be found at [provider#clipboard#Executable](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/v0.4.3/runtime/autoload/provider/clipboard.vim#L65).

While this solution requires installing an external binary [`win32yank.exe`](https://github.com/equalsraf/win32yank), I'm personally very satisfied with it as both `clip.exe` and `powershell.exe [Set|Get]-Clipboard` pale in user experience to it. For example, `clip.exe` only supports copying, but fails to address the pasting issue. And while the Powershell `Get-Clipboard` cmdlet allows for us to paste into Vim from our Windows clipboard, it'll retain Windows line-endings, so there will be nasty `^M`s everywhere after pasting. In addition, it's a super small binary and only has to be installed within our WSL distro; nothing on the Windows side.

```
curl -sLo /tmp/win32yank.zip https://github.com/equalsraf/win32yank/releases/download/v0.0.4/win32yank-x64.zip
unzip -p /tmp/win32yank.zip win32yank.exe > /tmp/win32yank.exe
chmod +x /tmp/win32yank.exe
sudo mv /tmp/win32yank.exe /usr/local/bin/
```

### Vim

If we're just using regular Vim, we can still use `win32yank.exe`, but we have to manually implement what Neovim would normally do for us. That is, the following:

```
set clipboard=unnamed

autocmd TextYankPost * call system('win32yank.exe -i --crlf', @")

function! Paste(mode)
    let @" = system('win32yank.exe -o --lf')
    return a:mode
endfunction

map <expr> p Paste('p')
map <expr> P Paste('P')
```

First set the clipboard to the default register (`@"`) as the system registers might not even be enabled if Vim was compiled without clipboard support like on my default Ubuntu WSL distro. Copies use an autocmd to pass the default register to `win32yank`, and pastes intercept the paste to assign the system clipboard to the default register.

This works but it's noticeably jittery if performing several successive yanks and pastes quickly as we have to shell out every time. We can improve the yank by debouncing it:

```
autocmd TextYankPost * call YankDebounced()

function! Yank(timer)
    call system('win32yank.exe -i --crlf', @")
    redraw!
endfunction

let g:yank_debounce_time_ms = 500
let g:yank_debounce_timer_id = -1

function! YankDebounced()
    let l:now = localtime()
    call timer_stop(g:yank_debounce_timer_id)
    let g:yank_debounce_timer_id = timer_start(g:yank_debounce_time_ms, 'Yank')
endfunction
```

But this will require Vim 8, and if you have to upgrade, I'd recommend to just go with Neovim instead. Trying to implement proper caching and debouncing would be a headache!

Comment: Works even for WSL2. This is the best and most simple answer atleast for neovim users.

Comment: `mv /tmp/win32yank.exe ~/bin` renames the .exe to `bin` and places it in `~`. Are you sure you don't mean `mv /tmp/win32yank.exe /usr/local/bin/win32yank.exe` (for Ubuntu)?

Comment: I can confirm it works on WSL2 *but*, you need to be aware:

1. you should specifically configure `neovim` to use `win32yank.exe`. The issue being that if you have now (or later install) any of the other options with a higher priority (`xclip`, etc.) then they will take precedence and your clipboard will not work/stop working. 

2. `neovim` may start lagging (up to 5 seconds) when doing things like cut/delete. This is likely due to the communication between Win and the Linux (hyper-v) VM.

Comment: The `Vim` section worked for me using `vim-nox`. This was the fourth solution I tried. (I haven't bothered with the debounce yet)

Comment: Note that it is the `p`/`P` commands that read the clipboard contents into the register. This means you can't access the register directly _before_ using either of those two commands. In particular, `i<C-R>"` does not work immediately. This also changes the behaviour of `xp` to be in-place.

Comment: I have *"WSL Debian"* with the `win32yank.exe` successfully installed. I can call it like `win32yank.exe --help` and get a response. But then I add `set clipboard=unnamedplus` in the `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` and nothing works inside the Neovim. Why would that be? @AntonOfTheWoods I made sure to uninstall `xclip` and `xset`.

Comment: @71GA have a look at my answer on SuperUser https://superuser.com/questions/1291425/windows-subsystem-linux-make-vim-use-the-clipboard/1557751#1557751. Maybe also try putting in the full unix path to win32yank.exe if the copy isn't working.

Comment: I settled for another better solution. I use X server on windows now, and do everything inside WSL as I did in Linux.

Answer (score 7):

If you only care about copying complete lines, you can use Vim's ability to pipe the file contents to an external program. So you can do

`:w !clip.exe`

to pipe into `clip.exe`. If you need specific lines, say 2 through 10, you can just do

```
:2,10w !clip.exe
```

See [Piping buffer to external command in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867356/piping-buffer-to-external-command-in-vim?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to set up an X server, this method will allow you to copy selected text to your clipboard using the `clip.exe` program which comes shipped with Windows.

The code snippets below can be placed in your [`.vimrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10921485/5660258) file.

First create a helper function which will return the currently selected text as a string. We can use this function to pipe highlighted text into `clip.exe`:

```
func! GetSelectedText()
    normal gv"xy
    let result = getreg("x")
    return result
endfunc
```

The `system` function will allow us to call native programs and pipe parameters into them. The snippet below sets up two key mappings; the first line will allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to be used for copying text and the second will allow <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for cutting text:

```
noremap <C-C> :call system('clip.exe', GetSelectedText())<CR>
noremap <C-X> :call system('clip.exe', GetSelectedText())<CR>gvx
```

After saving the changes to your `.vimrc` file you should be good to go.

If you are going to be using your `.vimrc` on multiple systems, I suggest wrapping these mappings in an `if` statement to check if `clip.exe` actually exists:

```
if !has("clipboard") && executable("clip.exe")
    noremap <C-C> :call system('clip.exe', GetSelectedText())<CR>
    noremap <C-X> :call system('clip.exe', GetSelectedText())<CR>gvx
endif
```

The above will also allow Vim to ignore those key bindings if it has direct access to the system clipboard.

You might also want to add keybindings for when vim does have access to the clipboard, like so:

```
if has("clipboard")
    vnoremap <C-X> "+x
    vnoremap <S-Del> "+x

    vnoremap <C-C> "+y
    vnoremap <C-Insert> "+y

    map <C-V>       "+gP
    map <S-Insert>      "+gP

    cmap <C-V>      <C-R>+
    cmap <S-Insert>     <C-R>+
endif
```

Which will come in handy if you are using Vim natively on Windows or are using `vim-gtk` on a Linux system.

Comment: Better solution than accepted imo due to no need for a buffer file. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 5):

Add following to `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event.operator ==# 'y' | call system('/mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe', @0) | endif
```

For convenience, if desired, you can add copying by `ctrl + c`

```
vmap <C-c> y
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use vim that bundled within WSL, you can only use the Clipboard provided by vim itself, which means you can only copy & paste within vim only.

Or, you can try:

1. Install [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) and run it.
2. `export DISPLAY=localhost:0` in your WSL Bash.
3. Run vim-gtk or vim-gnome(or any other GUI Apps) and try Clipboard across Linux and Windows.

Comment: According to a WSL GitHub-Issue, this should work. See also here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/892#issuecomment-275873108

Answer (score 0):

Combining the information above, it's possible to copy simple text from any register to a clipboard without using any keybinding (what can be more convenient in some cases). For example, if you want to copy last yanked text to the windows clipboard, enter the following command (start typing):

```
:call system('clip.exe', '
```

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, followed by a register <kbd>+</kbd>. It will paste a text from the specified register. Next, close the single quote and the parentheses. The command will look like:

```
:call system('clip.exe', 'a text from 0 register')
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, done!

Answer (score 0):

Below are mappings

- in normal mode `cy`, `cyy` and `cY` (=Clipboard Yank) that copy, respectively, the given text object, line(s), rest of the line from the cursor position to the clipboard, and
- in visual mode `Y` that copies the visual selection to the clipboard,

independent of whether Vim is started in WSL or not.

```
nnoremap                    cy                   "+y
nnoremap                    <sid>(mgu)   m`_
onoremap                    <sid>(gu)        g_
nnoremap                    <sid>(ggg)   g``
nmap         <expr>     cyy                  '<sid>(mgu)cy' . v:count1 . '<sid>(gu)' . '<sid>(ggg)'
nmap                            cY                   cy<sid>(gu)

xnoremap Y  "+y

if has('unix') && executable('clip.exe')
    " From :help map-operator
    function! SendToClip(type, ...) abort
        if a:0
            " Visual mode
            normal! gv"+y
        elseif a:type ==# 'line'
            normal! '[V']"+y
        elseif a:type ==# 'char'
            normal! `[v`]"+y
        endif

        call system('clip.exe', @+)
    endfunction

    nnoremap <silent> cy            :set operatorfunc=SendToClip<cr>g@
    xnoremap <silent> Y             :<C-U>call SendToClip(visualmode(),1)<cr>
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vmap <silent> <leader>y :w !clip.exe<CR><CR>
"---------------------- :w !clip.exe
" The core command, thanks to Mitchell's answer.
"---------------------------------- <CR><CR>
" The first <CR> closes the command;
" the second <CR> suppresses "Press ENTER or type command to continue".
"--- :h map-silent
" This fix the flicker caused by external commands and <CR><CR>.
"------------ :h leader
" `:echo mapleader` to view your leader key.
```

Standing on the shoulders of giants, I'm using the above solution now.

Answer (score -1):

What works for me is simply:

Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and selecting the text you would like to copy using the mouse. Then go to any text editor on your host and paste; your selected text should be there.