# Can I execute a MySQL query from Vim visual selection with output in a new buffer

Tags: mysql, linux, vim

Given a file which consists of multiple line MySQL queries, eg

```
SELECT foo, bar, etc
FROM blah
WHERE something or other
LIMIT etc
```

Is there any way I can visually select a query in Vim, pipe it through MySQL, and see the query and result in a new buffer?

Clarification: I don't want tabular output, but something that can be further processed in vim or imported into a spreadsheet (like the tab-separated output that you get from mysql --batch) 
(Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: Unfortunately, Michael's answer relies on changing the dbext source but it is such a great script that I have to accept it. (My answer does do what I asked for, but without all the power and flexibility of dbext)

Comment: Thanks to David Fishburn (the script maintainer) and Michael's help, dbext now (as of v15.0) does exactly that I need!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`Dbext` plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) supports this behavior.

Visually select the SQL statement, and run `:DBExecRangeSQL` to execute it.

The result will be returned into a new split at the bottom of your current viewport.

There are lots and lots of options for controlling the output window.  See `:help dbext` for the glorious details.

[image: dbext example output]

#### Update 1.May.2012

Version 15.0 of the plugin has been released with this functionality built in.

The default `-t` flag can be overridden

**Default setting:**

```
let g:dbext_default_MYSQL_extra = '-t'
```

**Overridden for batch setting**

```
let g:dbext_default_MYSQL_extra = '--batch --raw'
```

<strike>Dbext hard-codes the `-t` option to MySQL, but if that line is removed from dbext.vim, on line 2278 in DB_MYSQL_execSql (of my current version), you can pass the --batch and --raw options:</strike>

```
:DBSetOption MYSQL_cmd_options='--batch --raw'
```

To restore tabular output:

```
:DBSetOption MYSQL_cmd_options='-t'
```

I tested this successfully on my installation.

Comment: Dbext is going to come in very useful - thank you. I wasn't clear enough in my question that I need non-tabular data that I can then export as csv or import into a spreadsheet. I've played/googled around with Dbext but I can't see any --batch --raw options.

Comment: @Ken There's an option `dbext_default_MYSQL_cmd_options` which I think you can pass --batch --raw to.

Comment: @Ken I've never used it and so am not certain of the syntax but it's mentioned in `:help dbext-configure-options`

Comment: Looks like it should be `:DBSetOption MYSQL_cmd_options='--batch --raw'`

Comment: I've tried "let g:dbext_default_MYSQL_cmd_options = '--batch --raw'" and it doesn't make any difference.

I also tried "let g:dbext_default_MYSQL_cmd_options='--batch --raw --argh'" and it gives an error on 'argh' - so it is reading the option, just ignoring it: mysql: unknown option '--argh'

Comment: @Ken Yeah, I'm seeing something consistent with that. MySQL is getting the option and I saw it on the command line when I had one fail for another reason, but MySQL didn't honor it ??  :-/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what is happening - the plugin seems to be ignoring/overriding the '--batch -raw' options and doing it's own thing.

Comment: I did what I should have originally and went into the source. 
Unfortunately DB_MYSQL_execSql (in dbext.vim) has a '-t' option hardcoded in. I can inject '--batch --raw' before or after it (using extra or cmd_options)  but nothing seems to override that '-t'

Comment: @Ken Sounds like you need to comment out that line in dbext.vim then

Comment: @Ken I tested and batch/raw work properly after removing the line.

Comment: @Ken This has been bugging me all week, and my bounty rep felt ill-gotten.  I just sent the maintainer a patch to add `MYSQL_batch_output` (`--batch`) and `MYSQL_raw_output` (`--batch --raw`) options (`1|0`, both default 0).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Hi, could you tell me what font/colorscheme you are using in the screenshot?

Comment: @StasJaro I think that was jellybeans. https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim  I don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Michael and Zsolt Botykai for suggesting dbext and other vim plugins - they don't seem to provide raw output though.

I've put the following in my .vimrc, inspired by [Matias' answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585673/20074). This is my first attempt at vimscript, so caveat emptor...

```
function Query() range
    " use a temp file for result
    let s:tmpfile = system('mktemp')
    " single line copy of query followed by blank line
    echo system('echo '.shellescape(join(getline(a:firstline,a:lastline)," ")).
    \ ' > '.s:tmpfile)
    echo system('echo >> '.s:tmpfile)
    " pipe through mysql into temp file
    echo system('echo '.shellescape(join(getline(a:firstline,a:lastline),"\n")).
    \ '| mysql --batch --silent --raw &>> '.s:tmpfile)
    " and open in new buffer
    exec 'ed '.s:tmpfile
endfunction
" select query and <F5>
vmap <F5> :call Query()<cr>
```

Visually select query, press F5 (or :call Query()), and the result is opened in a new buffer.

It assumes linux (with mktemp) and gets connection details from .my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

Try the [dbext](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) plugin.

But there are some [other](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2081)s for this task.