# Modify textblock by external script in vim

Tags: bash, vim

While editing files I often encounter the following task: I have a standalone script that takes input and outputs a modified version of it (could be `sort`, could be a sed script, could be a more complicated python script) and I want to run it on a block of text within vim.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40290101/9437806) answer explains how to feed a text block to an external script and I assume that one can similarly read a script's output into a file using `:r`. But how can I do both: feed text out of vim to an external script and its output back into vim?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7867410/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+filter+external+program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter a block of text in vim using the normal mode commant
`!{motion}`. For instance, to use the external sort tool on the text below
(ignoring the fact that vim has it's own sort for now):

```
b
a
d
c
```

use `!ip` (external command `!`, `i`nside `p`aragraph), which will take you to
the command line with a prepopulated command line prompt (mine looked like
`:.,.+4!`) where you simply type whatever external tool (e.g. `:.,.+4!sort`)
you want to send the text to as stdin. The resulting stout will replace the
selected lines:

```
a
b
c
d
```