# In vim, how to send just part of a line as stdin to a shell command?

Tags: vim, stdin, vi

I'm looking at some obfuscated JS:

```
const f = Buffer.from("Lw==", "base64");
// select ^---------------------------^
```

How can I send the selection to `node -p` and replace?

I tried `:'<,'>!node -p`, but that produced `undefined`, because it sent the whole line instead of just the selected part of the line. It also deleted the indent and `const f =` , which I didn't want to do.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575545/vim-pipe-selected-text-to-shell-cmd-and-receive-output-on-vim-info-command-line answer your question?

Comment: Not really. It only deals with full lines, not parts of lines.

Answer (score 2):

Ex commands operate on lines, not on arbitrary text, so you can forget about `:w` or `:!`.

Here is a working solution but I'm afraid there is no dedicated built-in method so you won't be able to avoid at least *some* level of complexity:

```
v<motion>
:'<,'>s/\%V.*\%V/\=system('node -p ' . shellescape(submatch(0) . '.toString()'))->trim()/<CR>
```

That's obviously quite a lot to remember and type but you can turn it into a visual mode mapping for more convenience:

```
xnoremap <key> :s/\%V.*\%V/\=system('node -p ' . shellescape(submatch(0) . '.toString()'))->trim()/<CR>
```

which you can then use like this:

```
v<motion><key>
```

But a real solution would also deal with sanitizing input and output, handling errors, handling multiline input and output, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
d
:call setreg('a', system('printf "%s" "$(echo '.shellescape(@").'".toString()" | node -p)"'))
"aP
```

This produced the expected `/` as output in the correct position:

```
const f = /;
```

However, it feels overly complicated compared to the linewise version. I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to temporarily isolate the selection to its own line.

```
<ESC>           "exit visual mode
`>a             "append after selection
.toString()     "modify JS before sending to node -p
<CR><ESC>
`<i             "insert before selection
<CR><ESC>
V               "select line
:'<,'>!node -p  "do the usual linewise filter
k               "go previous line
3gJ             "join 3 lines without adding or removing spaces
```

Unfortunately this will do strange things if the command returns multiple lines.